# Haskell: Can apply view pattern on conditional operators

Tags: haskell

Following is my sample code. An Engineer is said to be special, if his name is “Hari” (or) id is 13. I did this by using View Patterns. Can I apply view patterns on conditional operators ?

**Example**
An Engineer is said to be special if his id is < 50.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}

module ABC where
    type Name = String
    type NoOfReportees = Integer
    type EngineerId = Integer
    type ManagerId = Integer
    type DirectorId = Integer

    {- Define an employee type -}
    data Employee = Engineer Name EngineerId
               | Manager Name [EngineerId] ManagerId
               | Director Name [ManagerId] DirectorId
               deriving Show

    getEngineerFirstName :: Employee -> Name
    getEngineerFirstName (Engineer name _) = name

    getEngineerId :: Employee -> EngineerId
    getEngineerId (Engineer _ empId) = empId

    isSpecialEngineer :: Employee -> Bool
    isSpecialEngineer (getEngineerFirstName -> "Hari") = True
    isSpecialEngineer (getEngineerId -> 13) = True
    isSpecialEngineer _ = False
```

Comment: What is the question? Does this code work? If so, what do you want to do differently?

Comment: This code works for equality checks like 'getEngineerId -> 13'. My question is Can I do the same thing for >, <, >=, <= checks.                                    For example, when i tried "isSpecialEngineer (getEngineerId < 50) = True", it throws me error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works

```
isSpecialEngineer (getEngineerId -> x) | x < 50 = True
```

although, you will have to complete your getEngineerId function to return values for every type of employee.  Note that you can just pattern match on Engineer using old fashioned patterns also, and do this more safely

```
isSpecialEngineer (Engineer _ x) | x < 50 = True
```

Comment: @HariKrishna Indeed, the first variant will crash the program if the `Employee` is not an `Engineer`. The second instead will just fail and allow the next pattern matching case to be attempted. I would avoid defining partial (i.e. potentially crashing) functions like `getEngineerId`: if you enable warnings with `-Wall` GHC will help you to notice those potential errors.